# Finding end/start date in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Look at this MySQL table:

```
+------------+-----------+
| date_key   | stude_key |
+------------+-----------+
| 2005-09-01 | COM       | 
| 2005-09-02 | COM       | 
| 2005-09-06 | COM       | 
| 2005-09-07 | COM       | 
| 2005-09-08 | COM       | 
| 2005-09-09 | COM       | 
| 2005-09-12 | COM       | 
| 2005-09-01 | YUM       | 
| 2005-09-02 | YUM       | 
| 2005-09-06 | YUM       | 
| 2005-09-07 | YUM       | 
| 2005-09-08 | YUM       | 
| 2005-09-09 | YUM       | 
| 2005-09-12 | YUM       | 
| 2005-09-01 | DSA       | 
| 2005-09-02 | DSA       | 
| 2005-09-06 | DSA       | 
| 2005-09-07 | DSA       | 
| 2005-09-01 | JRA       | 
+------------+-----------+
```

It contains the days when a class took place, and student attendance. I want to know the students that gave up (stop going to classes) and when. A student cannot miss a class and return.

For instance, the course took place between 01 and 12 of September 2005. COM and YUM attended all the classes but DSA gave up on 2009-09-07 and JRA only got 1 class.

I'm trying to get a table with:

```
+------------+-----------+
| gave_up    | student   |
+------------+-----------+
| 2005-09-07 | DSA       | 
| 2005-09-01 | JRA       | 
+------------+-----------+
```

Any ideas on how to efficiently do that?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like homework. Can you show what you've tried so far?

Comment: Actually it's not homework... I've several thousands records to analyse. I just simplified. I've tried a count(*) group by student. This gives the most common number of classes attended, but I'm assuming the majority went to all classes. Then every student count(*) bellow that value missed some classes. The problem is... how can I know if they gave up or started going latter?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I believe you meant `count(*) group by student` (the \* without a backslash or not within a back-ticked code section triggers italics).

Comment: I think you may have over-simplified - there isn't an indication of which class the data shown represents.  It also isn't clear that the course ran from 1-12 but not on 3,4,5 or 10,11.  So, as things stand, I don't think that anyone can give a really good answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT MAX(date_key) AS gave_up, stude_key AS student
 FROM thetable
 GROUP BY stude_key
 HAVING MAX(date_key) != '2005-09-12'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're just after the last entry for each student:

```
SELECT MAX(date_key) AS gave_up, student
FROM [table_name]
GROUP BY student
```